# bash find, only delete files - order of arguments

Tags: bash, find, positional-operator, find-util

Say today is April 8th and I execute the following in bash.

```
cd /tmp
mkdir hello
touch -d 2015-04-01 hello
```

Then, say I want to delete all files in /tmp that are older than one day, but NOT directories and I execute this:

```
find /tmp -mtime +1 -delete -type f
```

Why is directory "hello" deleted if it's not a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The find command executes the expression in order. Since `-delete` is before `-type`, `-type` is never reached. Try:

```
find /tmp -mtime +1 -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

- [David C. Rankin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527099/45375) uses the correct *abstract* term, **expression**, to refer to the list of arguments starting with `-mtime ...`.
- The OP, by contrast, calls this list **options** [edit: in a since-deleted post].

Calling them "options" is understandable, but since **the very fact that they're *not* options is the cause of the problem**, **`find`'s terminology and concepts warrant a closer look**:

- The **arguments that follow the input path(s)** are collectively called an **expression**.
- An expression is composed of:

  - **tests** (e.g., `-type f`)
  - **actions** (e.g., `-delete`)
  - **options** (e.g., `-maxdepth 1`) - note that such options are distinct from the *standard* options that must come *before even the input paths* (e.g., `find -L /tmp ...`)
  - Note: The above is *GNU* `find` terminology, which is helpfully more fine-grained than the one in the [POSIX spec. for `find`](http://man.cx/find), where all three constructs are called by a *single* name, **primaries** (*BSD* `find` also just uses *primaries* in its `man` page).
  - **operators**: `-a` (`-and`) for logical AND, `-o` (`-or`) for logical OR, and `!` (`-not`) for negation; the alternative forms in parentheses are not POSIX-compliant, but supported by GNU and BSD find.
- **Operators combine tests and actions into Boolean expressions**.

  - In the absence of explicit operators, **tests and actions are joined by an implicit logical AND (`-a`)**.
  - **`-a` and `-o`** apply **short-circuiting** (see below)
  - **Sub-expressions can be grouped with `\(` and `\)`** to alter precedence (the `\`-escaping is to protect the parentheses from interpretation by the shell).
  - **Precedence** (highest first): `\(...\)`, `!`, `-a`, `-o`
- **Order matters** with respect to **tests and actions**.

  - `find` *options*, by contrast, are *not* positional, but *GNU* `find` by default issues a warning, if they aren't placed *before* tests and actions. To avoid the warning, and for conceptual clarity in general, it is better to do so.
- ***Every* test *and* action returns a Boolean**, and **short-circuiting applies**:

  - In the **typical case** - with `-a` implied - this means that **subsequent test and actions are NOT evaluated, once a previous test or action has returned false**:

    - `find . -false -print  # !! -print is NOT executed`
  - Similarly, the 2nd operand of an `-o` (`-or`) expression is NOT executed, if the 1st one has returned true:

    - `find . -print -o -print # !! 2nd -print is NOT executed`