# Bash - Excluding subdirectories using the find command

Tags: bash, shell, find

I'm using the find command to get a list of folders where certain files are located. But because of a permission denied error for certain subdirectories, I want to exclude a certain subdirectory name. 
I already tried these solutions I found here:

```
find /path/to/folders -path "*/noDuplicates" -prune -type f -name "fileName.txt"

find /path/to/folders ! -path "*/noDuplicates" -type f -name "fileName.txt"
```

And some variations for these commands (variations on the path name for example).
In the first case it won't find a folder at all, in the second case I get the error again, so I guess it still tries to access this directory. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or does anyone have a different solution for this?

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command , there is a `-o` option to add after `-prune`. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I indeed tried that, apparently it means something like 'or', if you like to excluded multiple names/paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my previous comment, this works on my Debian :

```
find . -path ./ignored_directory -prune -o -name fileName.txt -print
```

or

```
find /path/to/folder -path "*/ignored_directory" -prune -o -name fileName.txt -print
```

or

```
find /path/to/folder -name fileName.txt -not -path "*/ignored_directory/*"
```

The differences are nicely debated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command/15736463#15736463)

Comment: The first one did the trick! Thank you!! Apparently I don't understand -o correctly..

Comment: the `-o` flag means that if the 2nd part of the expression (the `-name` condition and the `-print` action) is done only if the 1st part (the path condition) is false.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [olivm's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750123/45375) and address the OP's puzzlement at **the need for `-o`**:

- `-prune`, as every `find` primary (action or test, in GNU speak), returns a *Boolean*, and that Boolean is **always `true`** in the case of `-prune`.
- Without explicit operators, primaries are implicitly connected with `-a` (`-and`), which, like its brethren `-o` (`-or`) performs *short-circuiting* Boolean logic.
- `-a` has higher precedence than `-o`.

<sup>For a summary of all `find` concepts, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592349/45375</sup>

Thus, the **accepted answer**,

```
find . -path ./ignored_directory -prune -o -name fileName.txt -print
```

is **equivalent to** (parentheses are used to make the evaluation precedence explicit):

```
find . \( -path ./ignored_directory -a -prune \) \
       -o \
       \( -name fileName.txt -a -print \)
```

Since *short-circuiting applies*, this is evaluated as follows:

- an input path matching `./ignored_directory` causes `-prune` to be evaluated; since `-prune` always returns `true`, short-circuiting prevents the *right* side of the `-o` operator from being evaluated; in effect, *nothing happens* (the input path is ignored)
- an input path NOT matching  `./ignored_directory`, instantly - again due to short-circuiting - continues evaluation on the *right* side of `-o`:

  - only if the filename part of the input path matches `fileName.txt` is the `-print` primary evaluated; in effect, only input paths whose filename matches `fileName.txt` are printed.

<sup>**Edit**: In spite of what I originally claimed here, `-print` IS needed on the right-hand side of `-o` here; without it, the *implied* `-print` would apply to the *entire* expression and thus *also* print for *left*-hand side matches; see below for background information.</sup>

---

By contrast, let's consider **what mistakenly NOT using `-o` does**:

```
find . -path ./ignored_directory -prune -name fileName.txt -print
```

This is equivalent to:

```
find . -path ./ignored_directory -a -prune -a -name fileName.txt -a -print
```

This will *only* print *pruned* paths (that also match the `-name` filter), because the `-name` and `-print` primaries are (implicitly) connected with logical ANDs;
in this specific case, since `./ignored_directory` cannot also match `fileName.txt`, *nothing* is printed, but if `-path`'s argument is a *glob*, it *is* possible to get output.

---

A word on **`find`'s *implicit* use of `-print`**:

[POSIX mandates](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) that if a `find` command's expression as a WHOLE does NOT contain either

- *output-producing* primaries, such as `-print` itself
- primaries that *execute* something, such as `-exec` and `-ok`
- (the example primaries given are exhaustive for the *POSIX* spec. of `find`, but real-world implementations such as GNU `find` and BSD `find` add others, such as the output-producing `-print0` primary, and the executing `-execdir` primary)

that `-print` be applied *implicitly*, as if the expression had been specified as:

`\( expression \) -print`

This is convenient, because it allows you to write commands such as `find .`, without needing to append `-print`.

However, in **certain situations an explicit `-print` is needed**, as is the case here:

Let's say we didn't specify `-print` at the end of the accepted answer:

```
find . -path ./ignored_directory -prune -o -name fileName.txt
```

Since there's now no output-producing or executing primary in the expression, it is evaluated as:

```
find . \( -path ./ignored_directory -prune -o -name fileName.txt \) -print
```

This will NOT work as intended, as it will print paths if the *entire* parenthesized expression evaluates to true, which in this case mistakenly includes the pruned directory.

By contrast, by explicitly appending `-print` to the `-o` branch, paths are only printed if the right-hand side of the `-o` expression evaluates to true; using parentheses to make the logic clearer:

```
find . -path ./ignored_directory -prune -o \( -name fileName.txt -print \)
```

If, by contrast, the left-hand side is true, only `-prune` is executed, which produces no output (and since the *overall* expression contains a `-print`, `-print` is NOT implicitly applied).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** (added behavior specification details)

## Pruning all permission denied directories in find

Using gnufind.

Specification behavior details - in this solutions we want to:

1. exclude unreadable directories contents (prune them),
2. avoid "permission denied" errors coming from unreadable dierctory,
3. keep the other errors and return states, but
4. process all files (even unreadable files, if we can read their names)

The basic design pattern is:

```
find ...  \( -readable -o -prune \) ...
```

Example

```
find /var/log/ \( -readable -o -prune \) -name "*.1"
```

---

\thanks{mklement0}

Comment: @mklement0, Thank you once more!! Now I am happy! (r1) thank for `-print` in `-o` trick! (r2) I added "a intended behavior specification details" to my answer. As general conclusion `find` in general is fantastic for simple things but "tricky" for "tricky" problems...

Comment: Thanks for encouraging me to do so, but which information do you mean, specifically?

Comment: some axiomatic translation of find args... `a -o b  = (a orelse b) print` ; `a -o b print = a orelse (b print)`  -- one of this days I will make a find-dsl :)

Comment: OK, thanks; I've added a section to my answer; let me know if you think it needs improvement.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the way `find` evaluates the expression you are passing to the `-path` option. 
Instead, you should try something like:

```
find /path/to/folders ! -path "*noDuplicates*" -type f -name "fileName.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that still gives the same error :(

Comment: Then maybe you could just "hide" the errors by redirecting standard error messages: `find /path/to/folders ! -path "*noDuplicates*" -type f -name "fileName.txt" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Also already tried to do that, but than it will still fail (when using the command in a shell script).. I tested this command on a test directory, without the problem causing subdirectories and than it works fine, so I'm pretty sure that this is the problem. But thank you very much for your help!