# How to properly scope the -or operator for GNU find? How do I find symlinks to executable files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, posix

I'm making a function in my shell script that looks like this:

```
getcmds()
{
    # find all executable files/symlinks in $(searchdirs) that start with 'upvoter-'
    searchdirs | xargs -i find {} -name 'upvoter-*' -type f -or -type l -maxdepth 1 -perm +111
}
```

When I ran this function from another location in my script, I was getting a whole bunch of output that did **not** start with `upvoter-`. I eventually narrowed it down to the fact that **find** was interpreting my query like this:

> find everything that's a file and starts with `upvoter-`, OR is an executable symlink at the top-level directory

I looked on the [find man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to try to find a remedy for my problem. I noticed `find` supported parentheses, so I tried this:

```
find {} -name 'upvoter-*' -type f -or \( -type l \) -maxdepth 1 -perm +111
```

and this:

```
find {} -name 'upvoter-*' \( -type f -or -type l \) -maxdepth 1 -perm +111
```

Unfortunately, neither of them worked. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The last command works as expected for me.

Comment: As an aside: The description of the broken logic - "OR is an executable symlink _at the top-level directory_"  -  is not quite correct, because the top-level test (`-maxdepth 1`) is technically an _option_, which means it is not positional and invariably applies to the _entire_ command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement [Jonathan Leffler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520112/45375) and @muru's helfpul comments:

- The ***last* command command in your question *should* work in terms of *precedence***:

  - `find` implicitly combines *tests* such as `-type` and *actions* such as `-print` with `-and` (logical AND; the POSIX-compliant form is `-a` ).

    - By contrast, `-maxdepth` is an *option*, which is *not* positional and always applies to the *whole* command.
    - For an overview of `find` terminology and concepts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592349/45375) of mine.
  - Your *last* solution attempt correctly uses parentheses to change the implied evaluation precedence to achieve the desired logic (`-or` has lower precedence than `-and`).

    - By contrast, the parentheses in your *first* solution attempt, `-or \( -type l \)`, have no effect on precedence at all, because they enclose a *single* test only (whereas precedence by definition only matters for *multiple* operands).
    - Note how `(` and `)` are quoted as `\(` and `\)` to protect them from interpretation by the *shell*; `'('` and `')'` would work too.
- However, **the `-perm` test likely does NOT do what you want it to**: as written, it tests symlinks *themselves* for being executable, as opposed to their *target*. Given that symlinks are *always* marked as executable, irrespective of whether their target is, you'll end up matching *any* symlink, even if it doesn't refer to an executable file.

  - To fix that, **use the `-L` option**, which makes `find` apply tests such as `-perm` to the *target* of a symlink.

    - Note, however, that there's a side effect: with `-L`, when `find` encounters a symlink to a *directory*, it descends into that directory (i.e., it processes the symlink's target directory as well), which by default does not happen.

With the above in mind, somewhat ironically, the need for parentheses goes away altogether, because `\( -type f -or -type l \)` can be replaced with just `-type f`, given that `-L` now ensures that a symlink *target's* type is tested:

<sup>Note:

- I've removed the `{}` from the following commands to focus on the `find` command only. Without a filename argument, GNU `find` implicitly operates on the current directory (`.` is implied); BSD `find`, by contrast *requires* a filename argument.

- Also, `/111` rather than `+111` is used as the permissions mask, because the `+` syntax was deprecated a while ago and was actually *removed* in GNU `find` 4.5.12.

- Finally, `-maxdepth 1` was placed *before the first positional element* (test `-name`) not only for greater conceptual clarity (as stated `-maxdepth`, because it is an *option*, always applies to the *entire* command), but also to suppress a warning that recent versions of GNU `find` would otherwise issue.</sup>

```
find -L -maxdepth 1 -name 'upvoter-*' -type f -perm /111
```

---

Additional thoughts about your command:

- `-perm /111` (`-perm +111`) applies *any*-specified-bit-set logic i.e., it tests whether the executable bit is set for *any* security principal; the symbolic-mode equivalent is `-perm /a=x`.

  - As stated, the `+` syntax was deprecated a while ago and removed in GNU `find` v4.5.12.
  - *BSD* `find`, by contrast, continues to *only* support `+`, which unfortunately means that no single command with this feature will work with both implementations with GNU `find` 4.5.12 or higher.
  - In any event, this feature is *nonstandard* (not POSIX-compliant).
- If instead you wanted to match only files where *all* execution bits are set, use prefix `-`: `-perm -111` or `-perm -a=x`
- Alternatively, if you wanted to test whether files are executable by *you*, use the `-executable` test (a GNU `find` extension).

  - Also, `-executable` "takes into account access control lists and other permissions artefacts which the -perm test  ignores." (from `man find`).

Finally, GNU `xargs`'s `-i` option is deprecated; the manual recommends using `-I {}` instead.

Comment: Well, that is one monstrosity of a detailed answer. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

The terms in the condition of (GNU) `find` are (implicitly) connected by `-and` unless you override it with `-or`.  So, your last `find` should work:

```
… |
xargs -i find {} -name 'upvoter-*' \( -type f -or -type l \) -maxdepth 1 -perm +111
```

Under the named directories, it will look for names starting `upvoter-` *and* files of type `f` or `l` (file or symlink) *and* to a maximum depth of `1` *and* with at least universal execute permission.  It won't find files with `750` or `455` or some other oddball permissions, but it will find `755` or `711` or `511` or other similar permissions.  With a symlink, it would be surprising if it did not look for the permissions on the file at the end of the symlink rather than the permissions of the symlink itself.  There is an implicit `-print` at the end when no other action is specified.

Note that POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) only supports `-a` and `-o` for *and* and *or* respectively.

Comment: I doubt `-perm` tests the symlink target's permissions without `-L`. (And of course, if `-L` were used, `-type l` would be unnecessary.)

Comment: @muru is correct: without `-L`, `find` tests the permissions of _symlinks themselves_ rather than their targets'. Given that symlinks to _any_ target _themselves_ always have executable permissions, the OP's command will match _any_ symlink. I suspect what happened was: The inclusion of unwanted matches led the OP to the mistaken conclusion that he still had an _evaluation precedence_ problem, even though his last solution attempt did fix _that_ aspect.
As is implied by muru's comment: Adding `-L` fixes the remaining problem (and obviates the need for `-or -type l` and therefore parentheses).